# Where laravel Syslog are on windows

Tags: laravel, logging, syslog, laragon

I'm running a local laravel APP with laragon, and I have this line of code:

```
Log::channel("syslog")->error('User ' . $request->email . ' logged in from IP ' . $ip);
```

After I search a little bit, I found that this logs goes to `/var/log/syslog`

But I'm on windows and with Laragon, so where this log goes?

I'm asking this, because I need to have logs in syslog format, so I'm thinking that I need to use syslog.

Its the any way to have logs in syslog format, but save them on laravel.log?

Comment: syslog is not used by Windows if i remember

Comment: You are correct, but its there any way that I can see those logs?

Comment: I guess no, since they're not used by windows, but you can change sys log to another channel

Comment: Windows does **not** use `syslog`. You'll either have to install a syslog server and send the logs there or use a `channel()` which is natively supported by windows.

Comment: Also, when asking a question, try to provide as much information as possible. This can make it a lot easier for people who want to answer your question. For more information see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).